# How to solve the second condition in this p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: java

```
package pks;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(foo(2134,2154));
    }

    static int foo(int n1, int n2) {
        if (length(n1)==length(n2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    static int length(int n) {
        int numDigits = 0;
        while (n > 0) {   // Assumes n is >= 0
            numDigits++;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        if (numDigits == 0) {
            numDigits = 1;
        }
        return numDigits;
    }

    static int nthDigit(int number, int n) {
        int digit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {  // Assumes n is >= 0
            digit = number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
        return digit;
    }
}
```

The output of this program is 1.

I need to write a function, "signature of the function `static int foo(int n1, int n2)`," that takes two integer arguments and returns 1 if these two conditions are satisfied:

1. The arguments contain the same number of digits.
2. A comparison of the digits in the arguments from right to left will find only one digit that is different.

For example `foo(2134, 2154)` returns 1.

Both arguments are four digits long. Tthey agree on all digits except the third one.

The first condition works fine and it is returning 1 when all the digits are equal in number, but I don't know how to solve second condition it is compulsory that I should use these two function in program.

```
static int length(int n) {}         

static int nthDigit(int number, int n) {}
```

Any help how solve the second condition?

Comment: Your title is very generic.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is obviously homework, I will not directly answer the problem. Here is some [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) that you can complete:

```
//initialize a counter to zero
//loop the number of digits in the number
    //compare the two digits at the current iteration
        //if they are different, add one to the counter
    //otherwise, do nothing
//if the counter is equal to one, the second condition is satisfied and the method should return 1.
//otherwise, return 0.
```

Comment: +1 for the "homework, so only pseudocode" thing. Btw., you could simply return the counter, returning 0 is not forced, only returning 1 if there is one difference (which boils down to "return the number of differences".

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through both numbers and compare the nth digit of each one, keeping a counter of the number of digits that differ. If too many digits differ, return false, else return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the ints to Strings and use charAt to compare

```
public int compareInts(int num1, int num2) {
  String num1String = Integer.toString(num1);
  String num2String = Integer.toString(num2);
  if (num1String.length() != num2String.length()) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    int differenceCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num1String.length(); i++) {
      if (num1String.charAt(i) != num2String.charAt(i)) {
        differenceCount++;
        if (differenceCount > 1) {
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code will throw exception in case num2String size is less than num1String

Comment: Consider using  `Integer.toString(num1);` rather than string catenation. The check that the strings are the same length before starting to loop.

Comment: @Youngistan You are right. I read the conditions wrong. I see that ints can be different sizes now. I am editing.

Comment: @RichardMiskin Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that is a better way to get the String. Editing